# T Flip Flop Application

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

Good day all.
     I am trying to process two signals to produce an output signal. I will be posting a picture for clarity (sorry if I used pencil, I am stucked at home).
My two **input signals** are **sig**, a 20 Hz and 50% duty cycle signal and **EN**, a signal that is manually controlled by user via switch. The time duration Thigh of **EN** (active-high) is expected  to be much larger than the period of **sig** (50ms).
What I want to do is make a digital circuit to create an output signal, **EN'**. EN' is created by delaying all edges of **EN** (+ and - edges) until the next rising edge of **sig**. I have read a little about flip flops, which appears to be an answer for circuits which require time delay.
Can anyone point me or suggest me some starting point for type of IC/flip flop that I might use?

I am currently considering T flip flop. When I look at what I want to happen (see picture), I see that I need delaying and toggling. I want to somewhat modify T flip flop such that instead of toggling Q when T = 1, the circuit would instead toggle Q only one time during every Thigh of sig OR toggle Q only during rising edges.
[image]

Comment: What you really want is a D flip-flop, which simply copies its input to its output on every rising clock edge. BTW, your diagram shows something else.

Comment: In Verilog: `always @(posedge sig) EN_prime <= EN;`